# FactoryBot - Override association with trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Say I have a couple of models, sport and player, of which player `belongs_to` sport, and sport `has_many` players. I then create factories for both of those as follows:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :player do
    name "John Doe"
    sport

    trait :with_existing_sport do
      transient do
        sport Sport.last
      end

      sport { with_existing_sport }
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :sport do
    name "football"
  end
end
```

When I open a rails console and run `FactoryBot.create(:player)`, it works fine and creates a new player and associated sport in the database. But when I run `FactoryBot.create(:player, :with_existing_sport)`, I would expect it to create the player, but then associate that player with `Sport.last`, but instead it returns:

```
FactoryBot::AttributeDefinitionError: Attribute already defined: sport
```

So in summary, what I'm trying to accomplish is the ability to:

- `FactoryBot.create(:player)` should create a player and a sport
- `FactoryBot.create(:player, :with_existing_sport)` should create a player and have it belong to `Sport.last`
- `FactoryBot.create(:player, with_existing_sport: Sport.first)` should create a player and have it belong to `Sport.first`

Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything in the documentation.

***edit***

**solution**

Thanks to Marlin Pierce, I ended up getting it working like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :player do
    name "John Doe"
    sport

    trait :with_existing_sport do
      transient do
        associated_sport Sport.last
      end

      sport { associated_sport }
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :sport do
    name "football"
  end
end
```

Now I can use the factory as follows:

- `FactoryBot.create(:player)`, which will create a player and it's associated sport
- `FactoryBot.create(:player, :with_existing_sport)` which will create a player and associate it with `Sport.last`
- `FactoryBot.create(:player, :with_existing_sport, associated_sport: Sport.find_by(name: "football"))` which will associate it with `associated_sport`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :player do
    name "John Doe"
    sport

    trait :with_existing_sport do
      sport { Sport.last }
    end
  end
end
```

If you do want a transient property, you should rename it to something different than the non-transient field.

```
trait :with_existing_sport do
  transient do
    sport_trans Sport.last
  end

  sport { sport_trans }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I had an incorrect understanding of `transient`